# How do I partition Rails app into logical parts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, web-applications

So I am a fairly seasoned Django developer and I've been using Ruby on Rails for about a year. I'm working on a project with, let's say, 100 models. In my actual scenario, I'm writing a "component" to the app, which requires 2 models, one of which I wanted to call `Event`, however there is another piece of the software which uses an `Event` model in a totally different context. In Django, this is resolved by splitting the "components" into "apps", and models can have the same name because they are in a different app.

Is there is a similar pattern in Rails to separate some models in their own package to avoid name conflicts, but also so that each separate component can have it's own README which describes how that component behaves? I don't require that it have it's own controllers/views, since right now we have a single frontend interface, but I would be interested to hear if there is a pattern for that too. I've heard the term "engines" in Rails, but that seems to imply a total decoupling and unidirectional dependency scheme like for a generic 3rd party app, where as in my case, there is still some coupling between this "component" and the rest of the app, but it still seems reasonable to have some way of grouping models logically.

Also, I'm wondering how this case is handled in general. When a web application grows organically to have tons and tons of models, is there a standard pattern for managing this complexity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use namespacing using modules for your models.

For example `Foo::Bar` or `Baz::Bar` like this:

```
module Foo
  class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  end
end
```

To associate this model with table `foo_bars`, you can implement the method:

```
module Foo
  class << self
    def table_name_prefix
      'foo_'
    end
  end
end
```